# Datarow field extension method for convertion smallint to int

Tags: c#, sql-server, int, extension-methods, field

I have a column in SQL Server of `smallint` type. I read the row including this field by Ado.net.

When I get `DataRow` of that SQL Server row, I try to convert it to integer like the following code:

```
int value = datarow.Field<int>("myColumnName");
```

Because the field is `smallint`, I think that I should be converted to `int`. But it throws an exception saying that

> Specified cast is not valid.....

I don't want to use `Convert.ToInt32` or other function. I want to use the field extension methods of Datarow. How can I do that?
**EDIT:**

```
datarow.Field<int>("myColumnName"); // doesnt work
datarow.Field<Int16>("myColumnName"); // doesnt work
datarow.Field<short>("myColumnName"); // doesnt work
Convert.ToInt32(datarow["myColumnName"]) // works but i dont want it
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [SQL Server Data Type Mappings (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx).

`SMALLINT` is a 16-bit integer in SQL Server, so it maps to `Int16` in .NET

Therefore, you should use

```
Int16 value = datarow.Field<System.Int16>("MyColumnName")
```

to read the value

Comment: This throws exception too. ConvertToInt32 is working. I dont know why extension method doesnt work

Comment: really sorry. it was tinyint not smallint. So your recommandation works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use,
datarow.Field< byte>("myColumnName");